# converting a string object in a list to a float

Tags: floating-point, valueerror, typecasting-operator

```
def get_info(file_object):
    file_data = []
    opened_file = open(file_object, "r")
    for line in opened_file:
        line = line.split(",")
        file_data.append(line)
    opened_file.close()
    return file_data

def get_avg_mag(file_data):
    sum = 0
    for line in file_data:
        mag = line[4]
        mag = float(mag)
        sum += mag
    print(sum / len(file_data))
```

When the above code runs, I get an error message saying

> "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because when you are reading the lines from the file, you are also getting a new line character in the end with every line. So your last element contains a \n along with its decimal value and hence ValueError: could not convert string to float.

Trying striping the new line by adding line = line.rstrip() as below -

```
for line in opened_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split(',')
    file_data.append(line)
```